# Is there any other way to register implementation to make it injectable by any derived interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm using default ASP.NET Core DI-container

My hierarchy:

```
interface IRepo<T> where T : Entity;  - (CRUD)
interface ICarRepo : IRepo<Car>;   - (CRUD + more specific actions)
class CarRepo : ICarRepo; - impl
```

Startup.cs

```
service.addtransient<ICarRepo, CarRepo>();
```

So sometimes I can directly ask IoC-container for `ICarRepo` and get it.

But how should I register my dependencies if I wanna get `CarRepo` by asking for `IRepo<Car>` ?

I know that way:

```
service.addtransient<ICarRepo, CarRepo>();
service.addtransient<IRepo<Car>, CarRepo>();
```

but it doesn't look like optimal way

Comment: it does not look like optimal because your implementation of `IRepo` is not optimal. The `IRepo` should be open generic and there should be an implementation for it like `Repo<T>`. T here could be `Car`, `Bike`, ... If the `Repo<T>` could not be concretely implemented (because the logic is much different among the various T's), you may have to create your own helper class to get all interfaces of a service type and register them all with one same service type. As far as I remember, `autofac` has one similar method called `AsImplementedInterfaces()`

Comment: I have Repo<T> but its abstract class, so it can't be instantiated. But in my case, as solution it could be make this class not abstract

Answer (score 1):

As you described

```
service.addtransient<ICarRepo, CarRepo>();
service.addtransient<IRepo<Car>, CarRepo>();
```

is one way of doing it. Since it is transient it shouldn't matter that each time a new instance will be generated. Though you could use the "forwarding" style here too.

It becomes more tricky when one tries to ensure that the same instance will be returned for `singleton` or `scoped` services. In that case you would need to forward the factory method.

```
services.AddSingleton<Foo>();
services.AddSingleton<IFoo>(x => x.GetRequiredService<Foo>());
```

A more detailed explanation can be found on [this blog article](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-register-a-service-with-multiple-interfaces-for-in-asp-net-core-di/).